# Are there any famous physicists that never went to university?

Tags: physics, biographical-details, education

With the restriction of physicists after the year 1900, were there any self-taught physicists that achieved fame without having gone to university?

Comment: Michael Faraday would suit but your condition!

Comment: If you accept an astronomer then Milton Humason did not even finish high school.

Comment: What about Ramanujan???

Comment: Ramanujan was not a physicist.

Comment: [Oliver Heaviside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Heaviside) left formal education at 16. He died in 1925. He borders around your date restriction.

Comment: Maybe this is sort of a trivia question: Which Nobel laureate in physics did not have a degree in physics?

Comment: This doesn't answer this question at all, but Witten didn't (officially) study either mathematics or physics until his PhD.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Eugene Wigner, NP 1963, studied chemical engineering and received a PhD in that discipline. De Broglie (NP 1929) started out in philosophy and history, but eventually switched to physics.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar-I would think it would be Gustaf Dalen since his prize was basically an engineering prize.

Answer (score 7):

A similar question was asked to the theoretical physicist Gerald 't Hooft on his page ['Theoretical Physics as a Challenge'.](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html) It is mentioned at the bottom of the linked page:

**Mr. Hisham Kotry came with an important question:**
"... Two years ago I decided to self-study theoretical physics by following the syllabus of a renown university and the advice from your page and now I'm half-way through the journey but I was wondering about what happens next? ...Do you know of anyone who got tenure at a physics department or any research institute based on studies he did in his own time without holding a university degree?"

---

T'Hooft quoted the following message from a contributor to answer a part of the question:

**3/04/06: Message received from John Glasscock, Bloomington, IN:** 
The only one I know of currently is John Moffatt at U Toronto, who was a student of Abdus Salam at Imperial College, London. He started life as a painter in Paris, had no undergraduate degree, taught himself, corresponded with Einstein, and was admitted, based on his demonstrated original work, at IC. (Source: Jo�o Magueijo, *Faster than the Speed of Light*. Perseus Publishing, Cambridge, MA. 2003.)

---

I'm not sure if the example I quoted satisfies the "famous" criteria you stated in your question, but I hope this helped!

Comment: It seems that self-taught is no-longer possible for one to establish himself in physics community.

Comment: John Moffat does hold a Ph.D so he technically has a university degree. He just doesn't have an undergraduate degree.

Answer (score 3):

The best example I can think of is [George Green](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Green.html). George Green quit his studies at the age of 9 to work with his father and eventually was owner of a mill. He spent the majority of his life as a miller but found time to work on advanced math and developed concepts far ahead of his own time. He published an [essay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_on_the_Application_of_Mathematical_Analysis_to_the_Theories_of_Electricity_and_Magnetism) on electromagnetism in a little known journal that would eventually have a wide reaching impact in nearly every branch of physics. He is the namesake for [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) and [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) as well as some other important mathematical objects.

Eventually he did go to Cambridge at the age of 40 and earned his degree but this was well after his most important work. So it can be argued that he achieved this without going to university.

An interesting case to mention is [Freeman Dyson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeman_Dyson). While he did earn a masters degree, he never earned a doctorate but was still able to work as a mathematical physicist. Many people, including Steven Weinberg, believe he should have been awarded a Nobel Prize for the work he's done.

Comment: The question wasn't clear but upon reading again I can see that it is stipulating physicist born after 1900. Which might void my answer. However most famous physicists even before 1900 were affiliated with a university of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you count applied physics (aerodynamics) as well, but if you do, I have an answer. 
The Wright Brothers never finished high school and never went to university, and they invented their machine in 1905, so that is after 1900.

Comment: @wythagoras-you are correct my friend,then the list of autodidact physicists is
(i)Albert Einstein,(ii)Stephen Hawking,(iii)Galileo Galilei,(iv)Doc Brown,(v)Gregor Mendel,(v)Ignaz Semmelweis,(vi)George Zweig & (vi)Ludwig Boltzmann.

Comment: @AnonymousTeacher: That is one weird comment. What is your point?

Comment: @RoryDaulton cc wythagoras: It was converted from an "answer" to a comment. It may be dealt with further.